# May not exceed $2.00, or 20% - whichever amount is greater

Tags: excel, if-statement

Good day,

I'm looking for some help on writing a formula (maybe cleaner) to

1. In any cell (say for this example in D3) determine the max amount of a tip that is allowed per the rules

I got as far as this
=IF(((B20+B21)*0.2)<=2,2,IF(((B20+B21)*0.2)>2,((B20+B21)*0.2),""))

and a formula to

2. In any cell (say for this example in D5) determine if the amount of the tip is allowed per the rules

I got as far as this
=IF((B4)<=D3,"Allowed","Not Allowed")

Rule: May not exceed $2.00, or 20%  - whichever amount is greater

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: =IF(((B2+B3)*0.2)<=2,2,(B2+B3)*0.2) ?

Comment: Yours is much shorter than what I had, why is that? Also if I wanted it to be left blank if 0, how would I adjust?

Comment: Well it is as simple as your statement in title: if total amount x 0.2 is lower than 2, then 2, else total amount x 0.2. To show max tip 0 if dinner + tax is 0, try =IF((B2+B3)*0.2=0,0,IF(((B2+B3)*0.2)<=2,2,(B2+B3)*0.2)) or a bit shorter with LET: =LET(z,(B2+B3)*0.2,IF(z=0,0,IF(z<=2,2,z)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** To return the maximum value between two or more numbers, use the MAX function. In this case, *number1* = `2`, and *number2* = `(B2+B3)*0.2`. Therefore, to return the "Max Tip" in cell D3, the simplest function would be:

```
=MAX(2, (B2+B3)*0.2)
```

If you'd prefer it to return 0 or "" when there is no data in cells B2 & B3, wrap it in the IF function:

```
=IF(B2>0, MAX(2, (B2+B3)*0.2), 0)
```

In this case, the only *logical_test* needed is `B2>0`, rather than `(B2+B3)>0`, because presumably there would be no "Taxes" if the "Dinner" amount is 0.

**(2)** Your IF formula in cell D5 `=IF((B4)<=D3, "Allowed", "Not Allowed")` is okay; however, there is room for improvement:

- First, you do not need to enclose B4 in brackets when comparing to
  D3. `B4<=D3` will work just fine.
- Second, when you find yourself using "<=" or ">=" in the
  *logic_test*, consider using ">" or "<" instead, with the *value_if_true* and *value_if_false* parameters reversed.
- For example: `=IF(value1 > value2, resultA, resultB)` will return
  the same result as `=IF(value1 <= value2, resultB, resultA)`.

As such, a cleaner version of your IF formula in cell D5 would be:

```
=IF(B4>D3, "Not Allowed", "Allowed")
```

**(3)** The layout of your spreadsheet is also somewhat inefficient. Consider organizing your data in a table, with rows and columns. For example:

| Dinner | Taxes | Subtotal | Tip | Total | Max Tip ($) | Max Tip Exceeded? | Excess Tip ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.00 | 10.00 | 30.00 | 5.00 | 35.00 | 6.00 | FALSE | - |
| 20.00 | 10.00 | 30.00 | 8.00 | 38.00 | 6.00 | TRUE | 2.00 |
| 5.00 | 1.00 | 6.00 | 1.00 | 7.00 | 2.00 | FALSE | - |
| 5.00 | 1.00 | 6.00 | 3.00 | 9.00 | 2.00 | TRUE | 1.00 |
| 25.00 | 4.45 | 29.45 | 5.40 | 34.85 | 5.89 | FALSE | - |
| 29.34 | 4.45 | 33.79 | 7.00 | 40.79 | 6.76 | TRUE | 0.24 |

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance and explanation on how best to make it cleaner. To the mention of the setup being inefficient, this particular setup is bc when auditing, I'll have to copy say just B1:B5 and paste it into a pdf to compare side-by-side to the inputted values

Comment: No worries! Glad to know the layout was intentional for a reason :-)